# How to fix an array of elements in my section. It won't display my work when I call the function...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each, indexof

So the idea of my work is with the 10 slides in my section will have an element append to the slides, which are drinking can products. When the cursor hovers the cans, the cans will increase the size to show the real detail of the can.

Anyway, I have managed to create my carousel active slide, the 3D effect cans that can rotate clockwise and have a list of different colour cans in CSS (different background for each bottle class).

I can only get the first can working on the active slide, but the rest of the slides are blank. I've only create a list of 3 items in the array hoping to fill up the three slides with the drinking can products but no luck? What am I doing wrong?

I'm calling the initApp function, which has the array of cans because I  want to append items, but only one at a time...

so in the each.function(index) - I can add the index, and then in initApp(index). and then in the initApp function I can adjust so that bottle[index] gets selected and then added. But nothing seems to work?? What am I doing wrong? I know there is a bunch of ways I can do this.

Like could I skip the initApp() function and add all the code in the .each(function() { my code to append bottle})??

```js
// slider

$("#products>article").on("click", function(){
  $("#products>article").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  animate();
});

function getActiveArticle(){ 
  var x = 0;
  $("#products>article").each(function(e){
    if($("#products>article").eq(e).hasClass("active")){
      x = e;
      return false;      
    }
  });
  return x;
}

function gofwd(){
  var activeIndex = getActiveArticle();
  var minArticles = 0;
  var maxArticles = $("#products>article").length - 1;
  if(activeIndex >= maxArticles){
    activeIndex = minArticles-1;
  }

  $("#products>article").removeClass("active");
  $("#products>article").eq(activeIndex+1).addClass("active");

  animate();
}

function gobwd(){
  var activeIndex = getActiveArticle();
  var minArticles = 1;
  var maxArticles = $("#products>article").length;

  $("#products>article").removeClass("active");
  $("#products>article").eq(activeIndex-1).addClass("active");

  animate();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  animate();
});

function animate(){

  var articleIndex = getActiveArticle();
  var totalMargin = 25 * (articleIndex+1) - (25*(articleIndex));

  var articlePosition = Math.floor($("#products>article").eq(articleIndex).offset().left - $("#products").offset().left) - totalMargin;
  var productsHalfWidth = $("#products").width()/2;
  if(articleIndex == 0){
    var halfWidth = 150;
  }else{
    var halfWidth = 100;
  }
  var finalPosition = productsHalfWidth - articlePosition - halfWidth;
  $("#products").animate({
    "left": finalPosition,
  }, {
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'easeOutBack',
  });

}

$(window).on("resize", function(){
  animate();
});

var autoPlay = setInterval(function(){
  gofwd();
}, 3500);

$("#slider").on("mouseenter", function(){
  clearInterval(autoPlay);
});
$("#slider").on("mouseleave", function(){
  autoPlay = setInterval(function(){
    gofwd();
  }, 4500);
});

// cans

const getElement = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);
const createElement = (tag) => document.createElement(tag);
// const addBackground1 = document.style['background'] = 'url ("https://i.postimg.cc/BZ8rj2NM/sleve.png")';

const addSideStyle = ($side, i) => {
  let deg = 3.75 * i;
  let bgPosition = 972 - (i * 10.125);

  $side.style['background-position'] = bgPosition + 'px 0';
  $side.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotateY(' + deg + 'deg) translateZ(154px)';
  $side.style['-moz-transform'] = 'rotateY(' + deg + 'deg) translateZ(154px)';
  $side.style['transform'] = 'rotateY(' + deg + 'deg) translateZ(154px)';
};

const createBottle = () => {
  const $bottle = createElement('div');
  $bottle.classList.add('bottle');
  const $bottleLabel = createBottleLabel();

  for (let i = 0; i < 96; i = i + 1){
    let $bottleSide = createBottleSide(i);
    $bottleLabel.append($bottleSide);
  }

  $bottle.append($bottleLabel);

  return $bottle;
};

const createBottleLabel = () => {
  const $bottleLabel = createElement('div');
  $bottleLabel.classList.add('label');

  return $bottleLabel;
}

const createBottleSide = (i) => {
  const $bottleSide = createElement('div');
  $bottleSide.classList.add('side');
  addSideStyle($bottleSide, i);

  return $bottleSide;
};

const changeBottleSize = (clickFn) => {
  const _bottle = createElement('div');
  _bottle.classList.add('bottle');

  _bottle.style['transform'] = 'scale(0.9)';
  return _bottle;
}



const clickFn = () => {
  const $bottleSize = getElement('.container');
  // const $bottle1 = changeBottleSize();
  // const $bottle2 = changeBottleSize();
  // const $bottle3 = changeBottleSize();

  $bottleSize.style['transform'] = 'scale(0.9)';
  return $bottleSize;
}

$('#products article').each(function(index) {
  $(this).append(initApp())
});


const initApp = (index) => {
  const $container = getElement('.container');
  const $bottle1 = createBottle();
  const $bottle2 = createBottle();
  const $bottle3 = createBottle();

  [$bottle1, $bottle2, $bottle3].forEach(($bottle, i) => {
    $bottle.classList.add('bottle' + i);
  });

  $container.append($bottle1, $bottle2, $bottle3);  
};



initApp();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Arial";
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #444;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 750px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

#products {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

#products>article:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#products>article {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 250px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.5); */
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

#products>article.active {
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#picText {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

#id {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 15px;
}

#gofwd,
#gobwd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 50px 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

#gofwd:hover,
#gobwd:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#gobwd {
  left: 0;
}

#gofwd {
  right: 0;
}

.can {
  position: relative;
}

.bottle:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg)
  /* translate3d(350px, 190px, 40px) */
  scale(0.7);
}

.bottle {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 10.125px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(650px, 190px, 40px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(650px, 190px, 40px);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(350px, 190px, 40px);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: scale(0.2);
  position: absolute;
}

.bottle0 {
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
}

.bottle1 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 500px;
}

.bottle2 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 700px;
}

.bottle>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -180px;
  left: -182px;
  width: 374px;
}

.label {
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10.55px;
  height: 679px;
  margin-bottom: 400px;
}

.bottle0 .side {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/BZ8rj2NM/sleve.png");
}

.bottle1 .side {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/Fs2RgnN6/passion.png");
}

.bottle2 .side {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/zGzJjm40/raspberry.png");
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

@mixin makeSide() {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <span id="gofwd" onClick="gofwd();">&gt;</span>
  <span id="gobwd" onClick="gobwd();">&lt;</span>
  <div id="products">
    <article class="active">
      <div class="container"></div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="container">
        <p id="id">2</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="picture">
        <p id="id">3</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="picture">
        <p id="id">4</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="picture">
        <p id="id">5</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="picture">
        <p id="id">6</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="picture">
        <p id="id">7</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="picture">
        <p id="id">8</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="picture">
        <p id="id">9</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="picture">
        <p id="id">10</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should put all relevant code in your question. All of them are blank for me in your codepen, and I don't see gofwd/gobwd   functions?  Lastly,  you're not returning anything from initApp.

Comment: @zfrisch sorry forgot to add the slider code file into the codepen project. check again, its in the project now. also, the relevant code is in my question. for example, when I have the code like this                                                $('#products article').each(function(index) {
    $(this).append('hello')
  });     each of my slide will display the word 'hello'

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your Javascript Console you should the following error:

[image]

you crated the `initApp` function as a `const` *after* calling it, that won't work. You have two options:

1. move the `const initApp` up, or
2. declare it a function like this:

   ```
   function initApp(index){
     // …
   }
   ```

Comment: mate thank you so much for this. I've been stressed out working on it for days.. just shows sometimes we need to rest and go back to the project with fresh eyes and mind in order to solve the problem.. however, https://codepen.io/Rosstopherrr/pen/GVRvxJ is it making your browser slow now that there is a loop of three 3D cans?